# Passing Alphanumeric Parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, alphanumeric

when i call a javascript function say, `onclick="doSome(this.value)" where this.value=123`, it works fine.

But if i call `onclick="doSome(this.value) where this.value=A123`, it is not working. How to rectify this problem?

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? did you get error?

Comment: Any time you are using non-digits, you are using a string. Strings must be wrapped in quotes. `this.value="A123"`

Comment: It works fine with alpha values: http://jsfiddle.net/kxLNG/ - Please show a proper sample of the problem code.

Comment: may be you need in your function to remove all alpaha chars if you want to use only numeral, but you code is correct, At least at first look

Comment: @RyanWheale : do you want me to try like doSome("this.value") which is wrong.. or do you want user to enter as `"A123"` in the textbox ??

Comment: @nnnnn it is working fine!

Comment: I think you missed the point.  If you are going to programmatically set the value, you (as the programmer) will need to wrap quotes around the value. `this.value = A123;` is invalid and won't work.  `this.value = "A123";` is valid and should work.  If you are only using numbers, then javascript kind of automatically wraps quotes around it (by converting the number to a string). `this.value = 123;` is really treated as `this.value = "123";`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. I had to call a function with a product code as a parameter . It was working when the product code is numeric and it was not working for products like "AE11002".

I fixed the problem by changing the method invocation from 
`onClick="decreaseQuantity(${product.code})"` to `onclick='decreaseQuantity("${product.code}")'`.

I think this will help you also.  Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. This is what I found out:

Example 1 (php):

```
$id2=125;  //$id2="D125Xz" works as well
echo "<a href='#' id=$id2 name='other' onClick='myFunction(this.id, 
this.name)'>anyText</a>";
```

Notes: example 1 works just fine using: this.id / this.name. However, using this.value / this.class it did not work.)

Example 2 (php):

```
$id3=125;  //$id3="125" works as well
$id4=6;    //$id4="6" works as well
echo "<a href='#' onClick='myFunction($id3, $id4)'>anyText</a>";
```

Notes: example 2 works just fine passing the parameters to the function either way (125 or "125")

Example 3 (php):

```
$id3="125A"
$id4="6" 
echo "<a href='#' onClick='myFunction($id3, $id4)'>anyText</a>";
```

Notes: example 3 simply won't work because of letter A within "". For some unknown reason, it will not pass any other but numeric data.